# Android Jsoup doc.select("");

Tags: android, jsoup

Using Jsoup
I want to print the *기숙사* in the txt class

```
<ul class="">
<li class="top">
<span class="num">01</span>
<span class="txt"> 
<button onclick="frm_search.searchKeyword.value=$(this).text();frm_search.submit();">*기숙사*</button></span>
</li>
            
<li class="top">
<span class="num">02</span><span class="txt">
<button onclick="frm_search.searchKeyword.value=$(this).text();frm_search.submit();">졸업증명서</button></span>
</li>
            
</ul>
```

doc.select(""); What should be in Double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it should be: **`span:containsOwn(01) + span button`**

```java
Element button = document.selectFirst("span:containsOwn(01) + span button");
String text = button.text();
```

See this [Try.jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/%7E2FZ_fgyFiCx1EqlNXNxwN1iG6ng) example to test and play around with different options.

This selector works by finding the `span` with the text "01", and then finding its sibling `span` (using the `+`) and then the child `button` element.